# Proxy and Cache certain ajax requests during development process

Tags: ajax, proxy

I'm working on a single page web app which needs to load a lot of data on startup. An inital load can take up to 10 seconds, which can be quite frustrating when you just want to fix/check a minor change.

There are two ajax calls on startup which require the most time. Ideally I'd have some proxy running which can cache these calls as long as I like. It should also be possible to disable these responses easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily using the AutoResponder functionality of Fiddler. 
Just save the response of query and map it to a rule in the autoresponder rules.